# VBA looping extremely slow

Tags: excel, vba

This is a data source.

[image]

What I am trying to do is to:

1. Add **9000** in each empty cell in **column D**
2. Concatenate **column D** and **E** in column **B** e.g `C2&"-"&D2`
3. Add column **E** and **F** in column **G**

For this, I wrote code which first checks cell **D2**, if it is `empty` then add **9000**. Then it concatenates **D2** and **E2** (`C2&"-"&D2`) in **B2**. Then adds values of **E2** and **F2** in **G2**. Then it goes to next row and select **D3** and check if it is `empty`. Code lopes over 6000 rows. Here is the code:

```
Range("D2").Select
For Count = 1 To (CellsCount - 1)
    If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then ActiveCell.Value = 9000
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
    ActiveCell = Cells(1 + Count, 3) & "-" & Cells(1 + Count, 4)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Select
    ActiveCell = Cells(1 + Count, 5) + Cells(1 + Count, 6)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -3).Select
Next Count
```

It takes approximately 10 minutes for code to run. Would appreciate if you can suggest me a faster way to run the code.

Thanks

Comment: Speed can be increased if you stop selecting each cell before setting its value

Comment: *Concatenate column D and E in column B e.g C2&"-"&D2*  ???

Comment: Sorry I mean to say column C and D not D and E

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do everything to all rows at once negating the need for loops.

```
with activesheet
    with .range(.cells(2, "D"), .cells(CellsCount , "D"))
        .specialcells(xlcelltypeblanks) = 9000
        .offset(0, -2).formula = "=c2&""-""&d2"
        .offset(0, -2) = .offset(0, -2).value2    'optional
        .offset(0, 3).formula = "=sum(e2, f2)"
        .offset(0, 3) = .offset(0, 3).value2      'optional
    end with
end with
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This code reduced run time significanlty

Answer (score 1):

Don't use select / offset. Prefer using cells(row,column).

```
For Count = 1 To (CellsCount - 1)
    If IsEmpty(cells(count,4)) Then cells(count,4)= 9000
    cells(count,2)= Cells(1 + Count, 3) & "-" & Cells(1 + Count, 4)
    cells(count,7)= Cells(1 + Count, 5) + Cells(1 + Count, 6)
Next Count
```

Comment: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/28700020#28700020)